# How many stacks do we have in applications

Tags: oop, stack

I'm an Electronic engineer and I'm not a windows programmer. I know how stacks work(in microcontrollers) but I wonder to know how it operate in a windows applications when we come across a definition like multi threading and so on. it should be one place to store but I want to gain some knowledge about it.

I would be appreciate if you introduce me some good references to read? 
Thanks

Comment: When you work with most modern languages (ex. C#, Java...) this is all handled on your behalf.  I can't speak for C++, but I can say that that level of management is not something I recall needing to worry about.  You'll find that the types of problems you solve are completely different than what you're used to.

Comment: Asking for offsite references is off topic for stackoverflow. There are tons of references if you search google.

Comment: Thanks emragins, I've searched on google scrappedcola but I couldn't find any useful information.

Comment: I think your main confusion is that in any 3rd gen programming language, stacks are there but you typically don't see them. The compiler uses them to do its magic (to store local variables, pass arguments to functions and  and to remember where to return when a function is done). At runtime there will be one stack per execution path (thread). However, you may occaissionally want to use a stack in your own code (application level). Any general purpose class library will have a class for it. Then it is basically a LIFO queue. This kind of usage on the application level is rare in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your amazing comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad and will depend on many different things, but I'm listing a very common scenario of compiled native applications on x86.

Typically each thead has its own stack which holds local variables and function return addresses.  The stack is also typically how parameters are passed to methods.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your answer. How about the heap do we have separate heap place for each thread?

Comment: No, you should research on how C++ memory management works, it should give you insight into what you're asking.

Comment: cheers mate I searched on C# all the time. Thanks for your help.